# How to set minimum chunk size when using rollup?

Tags: vite, rollupjs

I am using Rollup with [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) and [vite-plugin-ssr](https://vite-plugin-ssr.com/).

The production build it produces with standard configuration includes a ton of tiny files, e.g.

```
dist/client/assets/chunk-adbd3755.js                                                            0.69 KiB / gzip: 0.43 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-adbd3755.js.map                                                        0.10 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-d703547b.js                                                            2.35 KiB / gzip: 1.15 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-d703547b.js.map                                                        7.79 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-860778e7.js                                                            0.95 KiB / gzip: 0.51 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-860778e7.js.map                                                        3.26 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-90693398.js                                                            2.37 KiB / gzip: 0.94 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-90693398.js.map                                                        10.18 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-a3b7c495.js                                                            2.21 KiB / gzip: 1.04 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-a3b7c495.js.map                                                        5.33 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-d321b675.js                                                            0.67 KiB / gzip: 0.46 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-d321b675.js.map                                                        4.34 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-c5fff223.js                                                            0.36 KiB / gzip: 0.23 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-c5fff223.js.map                                                        1.17 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-93f6d1e0.js                                                            2.42 KiB / gzip: 0.93 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-93f6d1e0.js.map                                                        6.81 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-84638231.js                                                            0.90 KiB / gzip: 0.52 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-84638231.js.map                                                        2.43 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-7b2a7fc5.js                                                            16.33 KiB / gzip: 3.33 KiB
```

I am assuming this is determined by Rollup configuration, and I would like to force rollup to target producing chunks that are at least 5KiB in size, i.e. if there are multiple small chunks, they should be put in the same file.

How do I do that?

At the same time, there are a few very large chunks that would benefit from code splitting:

```
dist/client/assets/chunk-79a47c16.js                                                            233.29 KiB / gzip: 65.45 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-79a47c16.js.map                                                        1090.09 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-338b0152.js                                                            295.43 KiB / gzip: 64.69 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-338b0152.js.map                                                        726.44 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-4bad2a7c.js                                                            850.46 KiB / gzip: 175.06 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-4bad2a7c.js.map                                                        1842.03 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-00222315.js                                                            1220.59 KiB / gzip: 341.05 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-00222315.js.map                                                        3558.01 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-41093922.js                                                            1387.07 KiB / gzip: 364.90 KiB
dist/client/assets/chunk-41093922.js.map                                                        5215.41 KiB
```

Same question but inverse: How do I split them into smaller files?

Comment: A related issue is being tracked [here](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/4327).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73264532/how-to-reduce-the-number-chunks-using-vite *(Edit: Heh, didn't realize they were both your questions. :-) )*

Answer (score 3):

As of this writing, you can configure `build.rollupOptions` and pass `output.experimentalMinChunkSize` to rollup. Note that the size is in **bytes**, not KB or MB as would often be the case.

On my local testing, I have not seen this being respected though:

```
// vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        experimentalMinChunkSize: 500_000,
      }
    }
  }
});
```

See also [the PR](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/pull/4705) and [the documentation](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-experimentalminchunksize).

Comment: (It "works" in the case I tried, in that it did produce fewer chunks. YMMV.)