# How to reduce the number chunks using Vite?

Tags: vite

Vite produces unreasonably small chunks (90% of all chunks are under 1KB with a few 300KB+).

Here is the full build log:

https://gist.github.com/gajus/0149233592085181331dde7076fc50b1

This is example website:

https://contra.com/p/gkOQlbLq-validating-postgre-sql-results-and-inferring-query-static-types

This is out Vite configuration:

```
import path from 'path';
import { default as react } from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { default as ssr } from 'vite-plugin-ssr/plugin';

const { VITE_BASE_URL } = process.env;

export default defineConfig(({ ssrBuild }) => {
  let build;

  if (!ssrBuild) {
    build = {
      emptyOutDir: true,
      manifest: true,
      minify: true,
      polyfillModulePreload: false,
      rollupOptions: {
        output: {
          chunkFileNames: 'chunk-[name].[hash].js',
          entryFileNames: 'entry-[name].[hash].js',
          inlineDynamicImports: false,
          sourcemap: true,
        },
      },
      sourcemap: true,
    };
  }

  return {
    base: VITE_BASE_URL ?? '/static/',
    build,
    plugins: [
      react({
        babel: {
          plugins: [
            'babel-plugin-relay',
            [
              'babel-plugin-styled-components',
              {
                displayName: true,
                fileName: false,
                pure: true,
                ssr: true,
              },
            ],
          ],
        },
      }),
      ssr(),
    ],
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/'),
      },
    },
  };
});
```

If you try to inspect this page using Google tools, it doesn't even load – presumably because of 200 JavaScript chunks that that page needs to load.

https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly/result?id=ULZhtOfQfp1Gxj2wYhyCUw

How to reduce the number of chunks?

Comment: You probably can do it with the chunkSplitPlugin, there's one for vendors also

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73161429/how-to-set-minimum-chunk-size-when-using-rollup